# See Cookie Values in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on a legacy app that required Internet Explorer. I need to view the values of the cookies the app is storing.

If I could use Chrome, I know that I could click the "Resources" tab, and view the contents of the "Cookies" branch. However, I can't find an equivalent in Internet Explorer.

Once again, this legacy app requires Internet Explorer. I cannot even open the app in Chrome (believe me, I wish I could).

How can I view cookie values in Internet Explorer 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the console you can write `alert(document.cookie)` and this will give a list of all the cookies saved for that document

Comment: ouch! I was hoping that wasn't the best solution. however, that's the best I came up with too :(

Comment: You could also try this tool, which you may find easier, although it requires another download: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/internet_explorer_cookies_view.html